# RegEx for detecting a string and a path in one go

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript, filepath

Here is an example of what regex I need [regex](https://regex101.com/r/R9G7Ws/1)

I have many of these lines in a file

```
build test/testfoo/CMakeFiles/testfoo2.dir/testfoo2.cpp.o: CXX_COMPILER__testfoo2_Debug /home/juxeii/projects/gtest-cmake-example/test/testfoo/testfoo2.cpp || cmake_object_order_depends_target_testfoo2
```

I need to detect the string between `CXX_COMPILER__` and `_Debug`, which here is `testfoo2`.

At the same time, I need to also detect the entire file path `/home/juxeii/projects/gtest-cmake-example/test/testfoo/testfoo2.cpp`, which comes always after the first match.

I could not figure out a regex for this. So far I have `.*CXX_COMPILER__(.\w+)_\w+|(\/[a-zA-Z_0-9-]+)+\.\w+` and I am using it in typescript like so:

```
const fileAndTargetRegExp = new RegExp('.*CXX_COMPILER__(.\w+)_\w+|(\/[a-zA-Z_0-9-]+)+\.\w+', 'gm');
let match;
while (match = fileAndTargetRegExp.exec(fileContents)) {
          //do something
}
```

But I get no matches. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will it always have the  `|| <stuff here>` at the end? If so, this regex based on the one you provided should work:

`/.*CXX_COMPILER__(\w+)_.+?((?:\/.+)+) \|\|.*/g`

As the [regex101 breakdown](https://regex101.com/r/JHKn6F/2) shows, the first capturing group should contain the string between `CXX_COMPILER__` and `_Debug`, while the second should contain the path, using the space and pipes to detect where the latter ends.

```js
let line = 'build test/testfoo/CMakeFiles/testfoo2.dir/testfoo2.cpp.o: CXX_COMPILER__testfoo2_Debug /home/juxeii/projects/gtest-cmake-example/test/testfoo/testfoo2.cpp || cmake_object_order_depends_target_testfoo2';
const matches = line.match(/.*CXX_COMPILER__(\w+)_.+?((?:\/.+)+) \|\|.*/).slice(1); //slice(1) just to not include the first complete match returned by match!
for (let match of matches) {
    console.log(match);
}
```

If the pipes *won't* always be there, then this version should work instead [(regex101)](https://regex101.com/r/y7SYOW/3):

`.*CXX_COMPILER__(\w+)_.+?((?:\/(?:\w|\.|-)+)+).*`

But it requires you to add all of the valid path characters individually every time you realize a new one might be there, and you'll need to make sure the paths don't have spaces because adding space to the regex would make it detect the stuff *after* the path too.

Comment: Many good answers. I will pick this one, because of the optionality of the pipes.Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Looks good, but you need delimiters. Add "/" before and after your Regex - no quotation marks.

```js
let fileContents = 'build test/testfoo/CMakeFiles/testfoo2.dir/testfoo2.cpp.o: CXX_COMPILER__testfoo2_Debug /home/juxeii/projects/gtest-cmake-example/test/testfoo/testfoo2.cpp || cmake_object_order_depends_target_testfoo2';

const fileAndTargetRegExp = new RegExp(/.*CXX_COMPILER__(.\w+)_\w+|(\/[a-zA-Z_0-9-]+)+\.\w+/, 'gm');
let match;

while (match = fileAndTargetRegExp.exec(fileContents)) {
    console.log(match);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my way of doing it with *replace*:

> I need to detect the string between CXX_COMPILER__ and _Debug, which is here testfoo2.

Try to replace all characters of the string with just the first captured group `$1` which is between `CXX_COMPILER__` and `_Debug`:

```
/.*CXX_COMPILER__(\w+)_Debug.*/
                  ^^^^<--testfoo2
```

> I need to also detect the entire file path /home/juxeii/projects/gtest-cmake-example/test/testfoo/testfoo2.cpp

The same, just this time replace all just leave the second matched group which is anything comes after our first captured group:

```
/.*CXX_COMPILER__(\w+)_Debug\s+(.*?)(?=\\|\|).*/
                                ^^^<-- /home/.../testfoo2.cpp
```

```js
let line = 'build test/testfoo/CMakeFiles/testfoo2.dir/testfoo2.cpp.o: CXX_COMPILER__testfoo2_Debug /home/juxeii/projects/gtest-cmake-example/test/testfoo/testfoo2.cpp || cmake_object_order_depends_target_testfoo2'

console.log(line.replace(/.*CXX_COMPILER__(\w+)_Debug.*/gm,'$1'))
console.log(line.replace(/.*CXX_COMPILER__(\w+)_Debug\s+(.*?)(?=\\|\|).*/gm,'$2'))
```

Comment: `.*` at the beginning and end have no effect, so they be removed.